# yarn run Error: spawn EACCES in JHipster

Tags: node.js, angular, jhipster, yarnpkg

i'm creating project with jhipster Version 4.7.0.
when i run the angular, with `yarn run webpack:dev --watch-content-base`
shows me error like below.

```
yarn start v0.27.5
$ yarn run webpack:dev --watch-content-base
 10% building modules 4/4 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: [ '/api',           
  '/management',
  '/swagger-resources',
  '/v2/api-docs',
  '/h2-console' ]  ->  http://localhost:8080

Project is running at http://localhost:9060/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from ./target/www
 11% building modules 13/20 modules 7 active ...modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.jsWarning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type infomation.

[at-loader] Using typescript@2.4.2 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /Users/user/Documents/myproject/tsconfig.json.

136040ms building modules                                                                 
303ms sealing
1ms optimizing 
0ms basic module optimization 
74ms module optimization
0ms advanced module optimization 
109ms basic chunk optimization      
0ms chunk optimization 
0ms advanced chunk optimization 
0ms module and chunk tree optimization 
0ms chunk modules optimization 
1ms advanced chunk modules optimization 
40ms module reviving
137ms module order optimization
22ms module id optimization
15ms chunk reviving
0ms chunk order optimization 
132ms chunk id optimization
200ms hashing
3ms module assets processing 
26852ms chunk assets processing
8863ms additional chunk assets processing
20ms recording
0ms additional asset processing 
0ms chunk asset optimization 
 94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Ok, 0.256 sec.
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation started...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation completed...
1052ms asset optimization
 95% emittingMergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:325:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:493:9)
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:208:15)
    at Object.module.exports.fileCommand (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/node-notifier/lib/utils.js:53:13)
    at NotificationCenter.notify (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/node-notifier/notifiers/notificationcenter.js:66:11)
    at module.exports.WebpackNotifierPlugin.compilationDone (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack-notifier/index.js:62:18)
    at Compiler.applyPlugins (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:61:14)
    at Watching._done (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:104:17)
    at compiler.emitRecords.err (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:78:19)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:375:38)
    at compiler.emitAssets.err (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:61:20)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at next (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:220:14)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/merge-jsons-webpack-plugin/index.js:47:17)
    at next (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:220:14)
    at callback (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:108:17)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:131:13)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (/Users/user/Documents/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:365:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

can anybody explain to me what is happen?
and how to fix it.

i'm running macOS Sierra.
NodeJS 6.11.3 LTS.

thanks.

Comment: thanks for response. but it's block and exit compiling. i'm running macOS Sierra, Node 6.11.3 LTS.

Comment: In the jhipster project to run the command is **yarn start** try this.